Probability of Drawing a Red Ball - Revisited - $~p(A|B) = \frac{p(A,B)}{p(B)}.$
This is a self-answer question that revisits this question, which  was recently deleted by a Community bot.  This surprised me, because my take on the posted question was that it was okay to answer because the original poster showed work in his posted question.  So, I answered the question, and my answer was deleted when the question was deleted.  I am repeating my answer in a (separate) answer-box.
For what it's worth, I am mindful of the comments of Xander Henderson in
this meta math question.

$\underline{\text{The Original Question}}$
A bag contains 5 balls of unknown colors. A ball is drawn and replaced twice. In each occasion it is found to be red. Again two balls are drawn at a time. The probability of both the balls red is?
Edit
"Again two balls are drawn at a time."
This is ambiguous and could be interpreted as intending that the last two balls are either drawn with or without replacement.  Initially, my self-answer assumes that the last two balls are drawn with replacement.  At the end of my answer, I provide the computation for the alternate interpretation that the last two balls are drawn without replacement.

$\underline{\text{Xander Henderson's Key Comment}}$
Bizarrely, the meta math question that I linked to above was also deleted, which seems weird to me.  Anyway, because of this, I have hand-picked the specific comment of Xander Henderson that seems to provide me with very clear guidance as to what constitutes a high quality question when the question is coupled with a self answer.

Context should explain to an outsider why the question is interesting, what tools ought to be used to solve the problem, what level the question is aimed at, etc.


$\underline{\text{Context}}$

In my opinion, probability problems often require significant intuition to grasp and conquer.  I regard this question as a clear example.  The question becomes much easier to conquer if you have the necessary intuition.
Unfortunately, the only way that I know of to develop this intuition is by struggling (for example) with 50 such problems, until the concepts seem to become second nature.

An experienced MathSE reviewer left a comment following my originally posted answer, in which he claimed that my answer was flat wrong.  This makes the situation very interesting (at least to me), because I then reviewed my answer and could not find a mistake.

The solution involves the application of Conditional Probability, which (as I indicated, unless I have in fact made an analytical error) becomes simple to apply, only if the problem solver has the required intuition. 
The basic idea is that $~\displaystyle p(A|B) = \frac{p(A,B)}{p(B)}.$

The fact that the original poster showed effort, and then (presumably) was only able to critique my answer by comparing it to some linked answer, seems very interesting to me. 
Ordinarily, one would suppose that the question is aimed at a college student in the middle of an introductory probability course, where the student has been thoroughly introduced to Conditional probability problems.
By this I intend that the student was introduced to a series of perhaps 15 such problems of growing complexity, that led up to this problem.  
In fact, I strongly suspect that the education given to this particular original poster was deficient, which explains the original poster's confusion.



For $~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,5\},~$ let $~f(k)~$ denote the probability of drawing 2 red balls, one at a time, with replacement, under the assumption that there are $~k~$ red balls, out of the $~5~$ balls.
Then $~\displaystyle f(k) = \left[ ~\frac{k}{5} ~\right]^2.~$
Let $~W~$ denote $~\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^5 f(k).~$
Let $~p(k)~$ denote the probability that there exist exactly $~k~$ red balls, given that both of the drawn balls (with replacement) are red.
Then, by conditional probability,
$$p(k) = \frac{f(k)}{W}.$$

From the above analysis, an explicit formula for $~p(k)~$ may be routinely computed.  Then, the final desired computation, that of the probability that the next two balls (again, presumably drawn with replacement) are both red is
$$\sum_{k=1}^5 \left\{ p(k) \times \left[ ~\frac{k}{5} ~\right] ^2 ~\right\}.$$

I might as well cover the alternate interpretation that the last two balls are drawn without replacement.  Then, the computation becomes
$$\sum_{k=2}^5 \left[ ~p(k) \times \frac{k}{5} \times \frac{k-1}{4} ~\right].$$
